# XML not validating against XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Given the following representative snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:j="http://foo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://foo" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3.2">
<xs:element name="Event">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>The Incident beginning and end date and time</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="j:EventType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="EventType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="j:EventDate" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="j:EventTime" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="j:EventType" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="EventType">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Beginning"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Ending"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

The following XML doesn't validate. Specifically, it won't validate the EventType attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeDoc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://hostedbykarpel.com/Schemas/ReferralDocument_2">
  <Event EventType="TypeOne">
    <EventDate>2013-12-18</EventDate>
    <EventTime>00:15:28</EventTime>
  </Event>
</SomDoc>
```

However, if I explicitly add the namespace inside the element it works:

```
<Event a:EventType="TypeOne" xmlns:a="http://foo">
  <EventDate>2013-12-18</EventDate>
  <EventTime>00:15:28</EventTime>
</Event>
```

The namespace is already declared at the root of the document. Why would I need to specify it again just to get the attribute to show up? The Event element itself validates just fine, it's just the EventType attribute that won't.

Comment: Please post a "representative snippet" that can stand by itself to facilitate reproduction of your problem.  Your XSD references non-existent elements `j:EventDate` and `j:EventTime`.

Comment: @kjhuges That would add another 50 lines to the sample. Those can easily be replaced with string types. The problem doesn't have anything to do with that. It also turns out that it's less of a problem and more of a collision with the XML spec. See Michael Gunter's answer.

Comment: I didn't claim that was your problem -- just trying to help you improve your odds of people spending time to help you.  You should post the smallest complete example that exhibits your problem.  Expecting us to stub things out, fix typos (`</SomDoc>`), etc makes us less likely to look closely.  Thanks.

Comment: -1: Make your title more specific. At least, add the exact error you're getting. There are too many generic questions _xml validation_ that doesn't help anyone else but the poster. You didn't even provide a valid xsd, as requested to let us do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this behavior is defined by spec for named attributes referenced with `ref`. I don't believe there's a way to change it. However, you could get around by not using `ref`.

```
<xs:complexType name="EventElement">
  ...
  <xs:attribute name="EventType" type="j:EventTypeValue" use="required"/>
  ...
</xs:complexType>
...
<xs:simpleType name="EventTypeValue">
  ...
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a bad assumption when I started reading the documentation about attributeFormDefault and that lead to me scrapping the whole answer. So, is there a way to work around the issue if I don't have the ability to modify the XSD?

Comment: I don't believe so. This is defined by spec. The simplest explanation I can find for it is here -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468564.aspx#xmlscmavdcmplx_topic04 -- but I'm still looking for the W3C spec that describes this.

Comment: I forgot to come back and thank you. You're right about the way the spec is written, and it turns out the XSD was probably not valid to begin with, but that was beyond my control. It just required some gymnastics when I generated the XML to at least make everything work.